# Diagnosing switch support for LACP and Link Agreggation

Tags: switch, lacp, etherchannel

How can I tell if an airgapped switch supports LACP and link aggregation?

Answer (score 0):

Find the make and model of the switch, then cross-reference it to the product manual or manufacturer's specifications list.

If you don't have physical access, check with someone who does.